# In Node.js, how can I load my modules once and then use them throughout the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I want to create one global module file, and then have all my files require that global module file.  Inside that file, I would load all the modules once and export a dictionary of loaded modules.

How can I do that?

I actually tried creating this file...and every time I `require('global_modules')`, all the modules kept reloading.  It's O(n).

I want the file to be something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
//global_modules.js - only load these one time
var modules = {
    account_controller: '/account/controller.js',
    account_middleware: '/account/middleware.js',
    products_controller: '/products/controller.js',
    ...
}
exports.modules = modules;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Using a magic variable (declared without `var`)

Use magic global variables, without `var`.

Example:

```
fs = require("fs");
```

instead of

```
var fs = require("fs");
```

If you don't put `var` when declaring the variable, the variable will be a *magic global* one.

I do **not** recommend this. Especially, if you are in the strict mode (`"use strict"`) that's not going to work at all.

### 2. Using `global.yourVariable = ...`

Fields attached to `global` object become global variables that can be accessed from anywhere in your application.

So, you can do:

```
global.fs = require("fs");
```

This is not that bad like *1.*, but still avoid it when possible.

---

For your example:

Let's say you have two files: `server.js` (the main file) and the `global_modules.js` file.

In `server.js` you will do this:

```
require("./global_modules");
```

and in `global_modules.js` you will have:

```
_modules = {
    account_controller: require('/account/controller.js'),
    account_middleware: require('/account/middleware.js'),
    products_controller: require('/products/controller.js'),
    ...
}
```

or

```
global._modules = {...}
```

In `server.js` you will be able to do:

```
_modules.account_controller // returns require('/account/controller.js'),
```

Comment: Do I need to put `var` in app.js? (when I first load this file in the first line of my entire app).

Comment: @TIMEX See the edit. You have just to require the module file.

Comment: I have 40 modules.  In every module, I want to require every other module. It will not load 1600 times? (40 x 40)

Comment: @TIMEX No, you call that only once in the main script (`server.js` or `app.js`). Then in the 40 other files that are loaded **after** `require("./global_modules")` you are able to do `_modules.something`, where `_modules` is an object that is global and contains the fields that you've set in `global_modules.js` file.

Comment: oh!!! I see. I don't need to include it in the other modules. Gotcha. Is it recommended practice?

Comment: @TIMEX I would recommend a variable name like `AppName` being sure that nobody rewrites it. It's the only solution, I guess.

Comment: What do you mean AppName? How would I implement that?

Comment: @TIMEX What he is saying is to ensure that you use an obvious variable name to avoid accidentally changing the variable. If you have a global variable, it will be the same across all files, so changing its value in one file with change it in the others. A global variable name like `x` is likely to accidentally be rewritten, where as a name like `AppName` likely won't be.

Comment: @TIMEX Having an application named `HelloWorld` I would recommend to use a global namespace named `HelloWorld`. You are welcome! :-)

Comment: @TIMEX I added a second solution: using `global` object.

Answer (score 4):

`require` already does it. Try loading a module, modify it and then load it another time in another place or file:

```
var fs = require('fs'):
console.log(fs.hey);
fs.hey = 'HEY TIMEX, WHATS UP?';
//another place of the same process
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(fs.hey);
```